# Svg path animation dosent work in react.jsx

Tags: reactjs, framer-motion

I'm trying to animate svg path but cannot do it. I'm using styled-components and framer motion.I want to animate this in to steps. First animation is proceeding but i cannot change duartion of this animation. The second one which is pathanimation on svg isnt starting.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Section = styled.div`
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
  z-index: 99;
`;
const Logo = styled.div``;

const svgVariants = {
  hidden: { rotate: -360 },
  visible: {
    rotate: 0,
    transistion: { duration: 10 },
  },
};

const pathVariants = {
  hidden: {
    opacity: 0,
    pathLenght: 0,
  },
  visible: {
    opacity: 1,
    pathLenght: 1,
    transistion: { duration: 5, ease: "easeInOut" },
  },
};

const PreLoader = () => {
  return (
    <Section>
      <Logo>
        <motion.svg
          vg
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          className="icon icon-tabler icon-tabler-letter-m"
          width="240"
          height="240"
          viewBox="0 0 24 24"
          strokeWidth="2"
          stroke="white"
          fill="none"
          strokeLinecap="round"
          strokeLinejoin="round"
          variants={svgVariants}
          initial="hidden"
          animate="visible"
        >
          <motion.path stroke="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none" />{" "}
          <path
            d="M6 20v-16l6 14l6 -14v16"
            variants={pathVariants}
            initial="hidden"
            animate="visible"
          />
        </motion.svg>
      </Logo>
    </Section>
  );
};

export default PreLoader;
```

I already tried diffrent solutions. Is there chance that svg motionpath cannot cooperate with jsx?